# Removing intersection between data frame based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have these 2 data frames:

```
df_test
  dimension1_id dimension2_id dimension3_id dimension4_id dimension5_id  \
0            -1            -1            -1            -1            -1   
1    1177314888     238198786    5770904146     133207291         Exact   
2    1177314888     238198786    5770904266   18395155770         Exact   
3    1177314888     238198786    5770904266   19338210057         Exact   
4    1177314888     238198786    5770904266   30907903234         Exact
```

and

```
df_merge
dimension1_id dimension2_id dimension3_id dimension4_id dimension5_id  \
0            -1            -1            -1            -1            -1   
1    1177314888     238198786    5770904146     133207291         Exact
```

I want to remove everything that is inside `df_merge` from `df_test`, based on the combinations of `dimension1_id`, `dimension2_id`, `dimension3_id`, `dimension4_id` and `dimension5_id`.

This is my code:

```
df_test = df_test[
(df_test['dimension5_id'].isin(df_merge.dimension5_id) == False) &
(df_test['dimension4_id'].isin(df_merge.dimension4_id) == False) &                              (df_test['dimension3_id'].isin(df_merge.dimension3_id) == False) &                                (df_test['dimension2_id'].isin(df_merge.dimension2_id) == False) &
(df_test['dimension1_id'].isin(df_merge.dimension1_id) == False) 
 ]
```

But this code returns a empty data frame. How can I just remove the first and second line from df_test?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use logical indexing to mask the rows you want by applying a direct comparison. In this case, you can check for values in `df_test` which are in `df_merge`:

```
df_test.isin(df_merge)
```

The resulting logical index acts as a mask:

```
dimension1_id dimension2_id dimension3_id dimension4_id dimension5_id      \
0          True          True          True          True          True   True
1          True          True          True          True          True   True
2         False         False         False         False         False  False
3         False         False         False         False         False  False
4         False         False         False         False         False  False
```

`True` values map to matching rows so we can simply negate the index using `~` to return only the rows you in `df_merge` which are not `df_test`:

```
df_test[~df_test.isin(df_merge)]
```