# Pandas DataFrame how to compare each cell of a colum with each cell of another column in another dataframe and drop matching ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, drop

I have an enormous dataframe (D1) which is just a column of ID's (around 700,000) and I have another dataframe (D2) which consists of data related to people and one of its columns represents and ID.
I need to compare each cell from D2's column of IDs with each value in D1's column. The rows with a matching ID, must be eliminated from D2.

Here is the part of the code I made to compare and drop but I think I'm not using the drop function correctly. Due to the dataframes being too big and my pc or google colab crashing due to lack of memory, I had to divide D2 in smaller dataframes and add them to a dictionary (dataframe_collection) which is then used again to join each of its mini dataframes into a bigger one and print a csv file.
What is happening is that the smaller dataframes are always empty and I'm being able to identify which IDs are present in both dataframes, and which are not.

```
times = math.ceil(D2.shape[0]/500)
print(times)
dataframe_collection = {}

for i in range(times):
  dataframe_collection[i] = D2.iloc[i*500: (i*500)+500]
  dataframe_collection[i] = dataframe_collection[i].drop(dataframe_collection[i][dataframe_collection[i]["ID"] == D1].index)
```

**Data set examples:**

```
data1 = ['23100100011930000021', '23100100011930000031','23100100011930000061','23100100011930000081','23100100011930000091','23100100011930000101','23100100011930000181']
D1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['ID'])


data2 = [['tom', '23100100011930000021', 'USA'], ['nick', '23100100011930000031', 'DEU'], ['juli', '23100100011930000061', 'USA'], ['charlie', '23100100011930000722', 'MEX']]
D2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Country'])
```

In this case, the last register ['charlie', '23100100011930000722', 'MEX'] should be left in the final dataframe and the other ones should be dropped

Comment: small data sets as examples would be handy, however, it looks like you should use similar solution to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37246977/8805842

Comment: @NoobVB yeah It's very similar to that problem. I tried doing it on excel but it crashes, it won't even let me filter the cells due to the excesive ammount of data that's why I tried solving it with python but haven't been able to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think this is what you are looking for:**

```
D2 = D2.loc[~D2.Age.isin(D1.ID)]
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. For some reason it isn't taking the each value of D1 IDs. It works if I explicitly write a value such as .isin(['122122121']) but it doesn't work by passing the dataframe column. Any idea of what may be causing this?

Comment: Are the types of the two columns the same?

Comment: Yeah I even tried converting them to the same type and it did the same thing. I think it has something to do with it not working properly with series, it has to be with a list such as [x]. I transformed the Biggest dataframe to a list and now it takes too long up to the point where it just stops. I'll try making it smaller like the other dataframe hoping that solves it.

Comment: It has worked, there were some inconsistencies with the ID column in one dataframe and the values weren't taken as the same, there was an extra space. Thanks for helping josepn.